# Creation Of Deleted Document In fireStore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Following piece of code to store map into FireStore

```
city="Firozabad"
db.document("Location/"+city+"/"+"products/"+p_id).set(map)
```

[image: Firebase console]

as the document name Firozabad not present initially hence its shows as deleted document in the console so how do I make this type of middle documents to show as not deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console isn't telling you that "Firozabad" is deleted.  It's telling you that it just doesn't exist.  It doesn't exist because you didn't create it.  What you did do was create a subcollection under a document that never existed in the first place.  Typically, you only make subcollections of documents that actually do exist, but this is what it looks like when the document doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks for your help, so is there any way to create a document "Firozabad" directly, without first creating document "Firozabad" and then its subcollections

Comment: Create it just like any other document, if that's what you need, at any time that you want.